# InverseFourierTransform takes me forever

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, fourier-analysis

I am trying to solve complicated PDEs using FourierTransfrom and InverseFourierTransform on Mathematica 12.0, but the code below does not give me a result. I do not get any error messages but the calculation just does not end. Is there a better or quicker way to solve them? Thanks in advance.

```
D1 = 10^-7;
D2 = 10^-10;
t1 = 0.1;
t2 = 1.9;
p1 = 0.05;
p2 = 0.95;
c0 = 1;
c1[x_] := UnitStep[-x]*p1*2*c0;
c2[x_] := UnitStep[-x]*p2*2*c0;
chat1 = FourierTransform[c1[x], x, k, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}];
chat2 = FourierTransform[c2[x], x, k, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}];
DD1 = 1/2*(D1 + D2 + 1/k^2*(1/t1 + 1/t2) - Sqrt[(D1 - D2 + 1/k^2*(1/t1 - 1/t2))^2 + 4/(k^4*t1*t2)]);
DD2 = 1/2*(D1 + D2 + 1/k^2*(1/t1 + 1/t2) + Sqrt[(D1 - D2 + 1/k^2*(1/t1 - 1/t2))^2 + 4/(k^4*t1*t2)]);
p = (chat1*(DD2 - D1) + chat2*(DD2 - D2))/(DD2 - DD1);
q = (chat1*(D1 - DD1) + chat2*(D2 - DD1))/(DD2 - DD1);
chat = p*Exp[-k^2*DD1*t] + q*Exp[-k^2*DD2*t];
c = InverseFourierTransform[chat, k, x, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}];
Plot3D[c, {x, -0.001, 0.001}, {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All]
```

By the way, if I use a simpler PDE, the code works just fine. For example,

```
a = 1;
D1 = 1;
c1[x_] := UnitStep[x + a] + (-UnitStep[x - a]);
chat1 = FourierTransform[c1[x], x, k, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}];
chat = chat1*Exp[-D1*k^2*t];
c = InverseFourierTransform[chat, k, x, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}];
Plot3D[c, {x, -2, 2}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

In this case, I get a nice and simple 3D plot like this.[image]